# php hour sheet, calculation with php and sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
    mysql -u X -p X -e "select hoursheet_2_details.parent_id, hoursheet_2_details.id, employee, hoursheet_2_details.hourtype, start, end, duration, projectcode, break from hoursheet 
    INNER JOIN hoursheet_2_details 
    ON hoursheet.id=hoursheet_2_details.parent_id"
```

With the following outcome:

parent_id   id  employee    hourtype    start   end duration    projectcode break

1   289 799 Travel   7.50   8.00    0.50    test     0.00

1   290 799 Work    8.00    16.25   8.25    test    -0.75

1   291 799 Travel  16.25   16.75   0.50    test     0.00

Now I want to get the work hours out and change these and import them back to a different table in sql.

So the Work hours are from 8 till 16:25 (which is quarter past 16) with a total duration of 8.25.

A employee sometimes has a lot of projects during a day so it is possible that an employee has a hoursheet of 10 rows.

The hours are in numbers so 1 o clock = 1.00 and 15:30 = 15.50 etc.

I need to split these hours in hours before 9 o clock and after 16 o clock.
I am trying to code this but Im having diffulties. Can somebody put me on the right track?

Wanted outcome:
        Variable T: Travel 0.5 + 0.5 = 1

```
    variable W9: Work before 9: = 1

    variable W916: Work between 9 and 16 = 7

    variable W16: Work after 16 = 0.25

    Variable W = w9 + w916 + w16 = 8.25
```

I've tried tweaking this:

```
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo $row[0]; // 42
    echo $row[1]; // the email value
    ?>
```

But also that doesnt really help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
      $result = mysql_query(QUERY);
      if (!$result) {
          echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
          exit;
      }

      $row = array();
      while($rows[]=mysql_fetch_array($result));

      //should not contain all rows
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r( $rows );
      echo '</pre>';
```